# Codeigniter passing 2 arguments to callback

Tags: codeigniter, parameters, callback

After posting a form having two fields named 'id' and 'url' I have the following code:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('id', 'id', 'trim|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('url', 'url|id', 'trim|xss_clean|callback_url_check');
```

A db query needs both fields.

The function url_check($str, $id) is called but in this case 'id' always has the value 0.

If I just do :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('url', 'url', 'trim|xss_clean|callback_url_check');
```

And call `url_check($str)` everything's working as it's is supposed to do.

The question is how do I pass two values to the `url_check($str, $id)`?

Comment: cant you just concat `$str.$id;` and pass it that way for the sake of validation.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use $this->input->post directly:

```
function check_url() {
   $url = $this->input->post('url');
   $id = $this->input->post('id');

   // do some database things you need to do e.g.
   if ($url_check = $this->user_model->check_url($url, $id) {
       return TRUE;
   }
   $this->form_validation->set_message('Url check is invalid');
   return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thorpe, that's genius. Great suggestion, this will totally work.

Comment: I did this without seeing this thread, and now I'm searching how to do this without the post inside de callback function because this is not general enough (at least in my function)

Answer (score 34):

Just do it the right way (at least for CI 2.1+) as described [in the docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('uri', 'URI', 'callback_check_uri['.$this->input->post('id').']');
// Later:
function check_uri($field, $id){
    // your callback code here
}
```

Comment: Callback parameters require at least CI 2.1.0.

Comment: That would be why I mentioned it in my post ;)

Comment: Should point out this is dangerous, what if "id" = "] is_numeric callback_check_uri[123" now they have just changed the rules of the validation and can execute functions at will

Answer (score 11):

This seems to work also.

```
$id = 1;

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Human Username', 'callback_username_check['.$id.']');

function username_check($str, $id) {
    echo $id;
    if ($str == 'test') {
         $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The %s field can not be the word "test"');
         return FALSE;
    }
    else {
    return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Jatin, Callback parameters require at least CI 2.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand form_validation correctly, each rule (set_rules) is for one field of the form and your callback will only check the one field.  In your case it would seem that 'id' is out of scope.  Instead, one can pass an array to the set_rules function and do the callback.  I have not tried this yet. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrulesasarray

Comment: +1 this is correct, CI's set_rules is just for one field per rule. You could use a helper function or similiar (or as suggested in your model)_, which isn't ideal but is the case here.

Comment: Thank you! You validated what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note on using the callback parameters as suggested in the other answers.  If you are using `app/config/form_validation.php` to create your validation rules, the  `$this->input->post('parameter')` syntax will not work since that object is not available in the CI Loader at the point in the execution where it reads the contents of that file. You would have to do the call in your callback routine e.g. :

```
public function _validate_user_signup($username, $password) {
  $var = $this->input->post('password');
```

In this case the second parameter passed to the method would not contain the password, but $var would after the call.

I hope that's clear.
Matt

Comment: You can use `get_instance()` to access the main CI object outside of your controllers, your models, or your views, example:
`$CI =& get_instance();`, see more [Creating Ancillary Classes](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/ancillary_classes.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use Form Validation library to get the data that is being validated.

Not always your data will be in $_GET or $_POST (see https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post).

The best way you can access your data inside a validation callback is this:

```
$this->form_validation->validation_data
```

"validation_data" is a public property in the CI_Form_validation class.