# passing a variable to callback function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

In codeigniter what is the correct method of passing variables to the callback function?
I have used this,

```
$var1 = 'some conditions';
$this->form_validation->set_rules("callback__is_value_unique[value, $var1]");

public function _is_value_unique($value, $var1){
echo $var1;
die;
}
```

This gave me output like shown below:-

**value, some conditions**

rather than,

**some conditions**

Comment: You can only send one custom parameter to the callback, and the 2 parameters in the callback function are the `$_POST` value and the extra one you sent.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822692/codeigniter-passing-2-arguments-to-callback

Answer (score 1):

You must only set your value!

```
$var1 = 'some conditions';
$this->form_validation->set_rules("callback__is_value_unique[value, $var1]");

public function _is_value_unique($value, $var1){
echo $var1;
die;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs..

> If you need to receive an extra parameter in your callback function,
>   just add it normally after the function name between square brackets,
>   as in: "callback_foo[bar]", then it will be passed as the second
>   argument of your callback function.

Sounds like you could only pass one extra argument. Which should be a string. If you want to pass more arguments, you could store them somewhere else and just pass an argument, which stores the location of the additional param.

```
$index = count($this->arguments);
$this->arguments[$index] = array('value', 'some conditions'/*, ...*/);
$this->form_validation->set_rules("callback__is_value_unique[$index]");

public function _is_value_unique($value, $index){
    $args = $this->argumts[$index];
    echo $args[1];
    die;
}
```