# Codeigniter Callback prevent adding duplicate firstname and lastname

Tags: php, codeigniter, callback

I need help on how to check if firstname and lastname already exists in the database and then call a callback using codeiginiter. I'm totally stuck right now.
Firstname and Lastname are two different fields by the way. Thanks

```
public function check_duplicate($str,$col) 
        {
            $res = $this->db->get_where("patients",array(
                'firstname' => 'Firstname',
                'lastname' => 'Lastname'
                ));
            if($res->num_rows()){
                 $this->form_validation->set_message('check_duplicate', 'The %s field already exists.');
                 return false;
            }  else {
                 return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of callbacks for that. You can use `is_unique` instead.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("firstname","First Name"."required|is_unique[tablename.columnname]");
$this->form_validation->set_rules("lastname","last Name"."required|is_unique[tablename.columnname]");
```

Or if you want to use callbacks, use this,

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("firstname","First Name"."required|callback_check_name");

public function check_name($str)
{
    $res = $this->db->get_where("users",array("fname" => $str));
    if($res->num_rows()){
         $this->form_validation->set_message('check_name', 'The %s field already exists.');
         return false;
    }  else {
         return true;
    }
}
```

So now you have to write 2 callback functions to handle form validation. You can make it as only 1 callback like this.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("firstname","First Name"."required|callback_check_name[firstname]");

$this->form_validation->set_rules("firstname","First Name"."required|callback_check_name[lastname]");

public function check_name($str,$col)//passing one more parameter.
{
    $res = $this->db->get_where("users",array($col => $str));
    if($res->num_rows()){
         $this->form_validation->set_message('check_name', 'The %s field already exists.');
         return false;
    }  else {
         return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your advice but still not working. Instead i replaced "." with a "," and now the system said "The Lastname field must contain a unique value.
The Firstname field must contain a unique value."

Comment: have you changed the table and column names.??

Comment: Which method you tried?? `is_unique` or `callbacks`??

Comment: Now it's working. Amazing. additionally is there a way i can change the message generated by the system?

Comment: use `$this->form_validation->set_message()`

Comment: The first method works just fine for me. I'll try the second one.

Comment: sure... If the answer was helpful, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: this is how you change validation message, `$this->form_validation->set_message('rule', 'Error Message');`

Comment: where should i put his line $this->form_validation->set_message()? Should I put it below the first method? sorry I'm new to CI.

Comment: Above form validation set rules.

Comment: Sir, how should i put data on the array if i have two columns on the table? like array ('firstname' => 'firstname', 'lastname'=> 'lastname')?

Comment: i did not get you... Add this in question with details, i can check there.

Comment: you want to check for both fname n lname?

Comment: yes, i have a patients table and i want to check both fname and lname at the same time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822692/codeigniter-passing-2-arguments-to-callback, see that link, problem is same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax and jquery here is a link on how to implement

http://tutsforweb.blogspot.com/2012/05/jquery-ajax-form-validation-in.html