# Unable to change value with codeIgniter validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Here i have a list of contacts where user can add new contacts as well as edit them. Now at the add time i'm using server-side validation by codeIgniter for reduce redundancies. Also here i have a number of users that can add their contacts.

Suppose their are users named "**John**" and "**Sara**".

In this case, whenever "**john**" add new contact that are prevoiusly added by him, then it can't be add as duplicate contact number.

But  whenever "**john**" add new contact that are previously added by "**Sara**", them it can be add . but its unable to add because CodeIgniter `form_validation` check unique value with entire table data.

**Here is my Controller Code**

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_email','Email', 'trim|check_email[customer.customer_email.' .$userId. ']', array('check_email' => 'Email must be unique.'));
    $this->session->set_flashdata('check_email','Mobile must be unique');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_mobile', 'Mobile', 'required|is_unique[customer.customer_mobile]');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('contact_exists','Mobile must be unique');


    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $userdata = $this->session->userdata();
        $userId = $userdata['id'];
        if (!$userId):
            redirect(site_url());
        endif;
```

I trying to many time but unable to fix this issue. I need your kind efforts. Thanks

Comment: remove check for `is_unique` and create a `callback function` for this. let that function check the uniqueness with respect to user name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below solution.

First you need to remove `unique` check from customer_mobile.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_mobile', 'Mobile', 'trim|required');
```

Once form_validation runs true then check customer_mobile with user in database and if it return row then `return error` else `insert Contact`.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
    // $check = Check here for customer_mobile with user in database
    if($check):
       return 'Contact already exist';
    else:
       // Insert Contact 
    endif;
}
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: isn't it better to use a callback function...?

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid: Inside callback function you can not pass multiple value, Here in this case he needs to check `contact_number` with respect to `user`.

Comment: yeah, but we use it like this [Thorpe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4825198/8317643)

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid : That is not a callback function, Please go here to learn more about codeigniter's callback function. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: Done. Thanks @ShyamShingadiya

Comment: So if your `$check` false then redirect user with `flash_data` or error message.

Comment: just loading view, i want flash message